# How to fix: Django forms: {{ form }} is not working in a dynamic html page

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap-4, django-forms

I've created a dorm in Django:

```
#forms.py    
    from django import forms


    class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    number = forms.FloatField()
    eail_user = forms.EmailField()
```

and imported in in views.py

```
#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Cards
from cards.forms import ContactForm


def index(request):
    cards = Cards.objects.all()
    return render(request,'card.html', {'cards':cards})


def contact(request):
    form = ContactForm()
    return render(request,'name.html', {'form': form})
```

I have created three html files, name.html, base.html and card.html. The form is showing up in name.html properly, however, in cards.html, it just shows a single button and it omits {{ form }} tag. Any idea how to solve the issue?
Thanks.

```
    #name.html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is base.html

```
#base.html
{%  load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="{% static 'css/stylesheet.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<section id="team" class="pb-5">
    <div class="container">
        <h5 class="section-title h1">OUR TEAM</h5>
        <div class="row">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is card.html which extends from base.html

```
#card.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <!-- Team -->
    {% for card in cards %}
        <!-- Team member -->
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="image-flip" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                <div class="mainflip">
                    <div class="frontside">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body text-center">
                                <p><img class=" img-fluid"
                                        src="https://sunlimetech.com/portfolio/boot4menu/assets/imgs/team/img_01.png"
                                        alt="card image"></p>
                                <h4 class="card-title">{{ card.name }}</h4>
                                <p class="card-text">{{ card.description }}</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="backside">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body text-center mt-4">
                                <h4 class="card-title">{{ card.name }}</h4>
                                <!--<p class="card-text"> {{ card.back_description }}-->
                                <form action="/your-name/" method="post">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    {{ form }}
                                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                                </form>
                                <!--</p> -->
                                <ul class="list-inline">
                                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                                        <a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">
                                            <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                                        <a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">
                                            <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                                        <a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">
                                            <i class="fa fa-skype"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                                        <a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">
                                            <i class="fa fa-google"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ./Team member -->
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Well, yes. Why would you think it would appear in card.html?

Comment: But please show name.html.

Comment: To render *card.html*, you're going to a url that uses the view `index()`. That view doesn't add a `form` variable to the context. So obviously, `{{ form }}` won't do anything. Only `cards` is defined.

Comment: @DanielRoseman name.html is updated.

Comment: @dirkgroten would you please make it more clear. I couldn't get my mistake yet !

Comment: @DanielRoseman name.html is updated.
I've created a form, I call it with {{ form }} in my cards.html. But why it is not appeared there? I created a plain html called name.html just to test if the form is working. The form is ok and it is appeared in name.html but, it won't be shown in card.html. I hope I could make my question more clear.

Comment: I don't understand where your confusion is. `form` is only being passed from the contact view, not from index.

Answer (score 0):

Function `index` is missing a ContactFrom initialization, that's why it's not showing up. Try this:

```
def index(request):
    cards = Cards.objects.all()
    form = ContactForm()
    return render(request,'card.html', {'cards':cards, 'form': form})
```